# Should I have Travis cache node_modules or $HOME/.npm

Tags: node.js, npm, travis-ci, yarnpkg

I'm quite confused about which directory is optimal for caching. I've seen both used and recommended, but no actual comparison as to why go one way or the other.

For instance, the Travis [blog](https://blog.travis-ci.com/2013-12-05-speed-up-your-builds-cache-your-dependencies/) [itself](https://blog.travis-ci.com/2016-11-21-travis-ci-now-supports-yarn) recommends:

```
cache:
  directories:
    - node_modules
```

However, [thousands of places](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22%24HOME%2F.npm%22+language%3Ayaml&type=Code&ref=searchresults) use this instead:

```
cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.npm
```

So why use one over the other, and why not include both?

Comment: [*Please note that as of July 2019, npm is cached by default on Travis CI*](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/#npm-cache).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I noticed caching the `node_modules` folder caused problems (build fails) while caching the `.npm` cache avoided it. I believe it's because the `.npm` cache doesn't store compiled native modules while the `node_modules` folder does. So when you test different versions of `node`, as is common in Travis-CI, it will try to load a native module compiled for say `node` 4 in `node` 6 and barf.

Answer (score 17):

Follow up on [@John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42523517/3001761).

To strictly adhere to package dependencies on `package-lock.json`, the NPM install process on Travis CI now defaults to the new `npm ci` (`ci` stands for continuous integration, I think) instead of `npm install`. This helps prevent installing packages that are not following proper semantic versioning.

To do this, `npm ci` needs to first get rid of the dependency graph and all the cached compiled modules in `node_modules` from previous builds so to restructure the dependency graph. It does so by removing `node_modules` entirely before it begins its own installs. But that also means `node_modules` can no longer be used as cache location on Travis. We must now use `"$HOME/.npm"` to cache, and @John has explained the reason using `"$HOME/.npm"`. Travis will throw an error at you complaining `"/node_modules/.bin/npm cannot be found"` if you continue to use `node_modules` as cache location, since `node_modules` has been deleted when running `npm ci`.

Now regarding which cache location to use...

1. `$HOME/.npm`

   When you want to use the now default `npm ci`, include these changes in your `.travis.yml`

   ```
   # [optional] `npm ci` is now default on Travis
   install:
   - npm ci

   # Keep the npm cache around to speed up installs
   cache:
     directories:
     - "$HOME/.npm"
   ```
2. `node_modules`

   If you wish to stick to the old `npm install`

   ```
   # Specify `npm install`
   install:
   - npm install

   # Continue to use the old cache location
   cache:
     directories:
     - "node_modules"
   ```

Warning: your cache location depends on the install method of your choice, and cannot be intertwined with another. Otherwise you risk losing the benefits of caching, or worse, have a failed Travis build.

You can find more about `npm ci` in the [NPM docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci).