# NPM and CI: --cache vs node_modules/

Tags: npm, caching, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

With GitLab I can cache `node_modules/` and/or I can cache the argument to `npm ci --cache <dir>`

What's the difference between these two options?

- Should I cache `node_modules/` between jobs and stages in my pipeline?
- Should I cache just the `<dir>` provided to `npm ci --cache`
- Should I cache both?

The [GitLab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#cache-nodejs-dependencies) show:

```sh
npm ci --cache .npm --prefer-offline
```

But they don't explain why I would not want to cache `node_modules/`.

Size difference:

```
❯ du -hs .npm
136M    .npm
❯ du -hs node_modules
932M    node_modules
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42521884/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/65490464/3001761

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference in my case was massive, by **NOT** caching `node_modules/` I reduced my CI pipeline timing between 30-50%.

It's faster to have every stage include

```
npm ci --cache .npm --prefer-offline
```

Then it is to move around `node_modules/` with a GitLab cache layer.

I suppose the data may work out differently if not using [containerized runners.](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html)

Comment: But even with a cache, `npm ci` is still checking all the dependencies, for me taking 50 seconds (down from 70 seconds without cache). The download-time seems to be less relevant than the version comparison. Are you using npm in a regular repo with one single node_modules or in a workspaces monorepo? Have you tried just caching node_modules WITHOUT running `npm ci`? multiple people have reported doing that makes their build unstable but I want to know details how so and if that can be prevented.